# Mapping a Long Type Column from Oracle to Nhibernate

Tags: c#, oracle, hibernate, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have a table in Oracle database with a column of `Long` type. In this column, we store a long text and we cannot change the type to `CLob` because there are other systems that use it as `Long` type. I am writting a new application to read this column and execute some tasks using `NHibernate` and `Fluent NHibernate` to map.

The mapping is ok, everything works except this column. When I read a entity from this table, the `long` column comes a string empty like `""`.

I have tried these:

```
Map(x => x.Query).Column("PNL_QUERY");
```

and

```
Map(x => x.Query).Column("PNL_QUERY").CustomType("StringClob");
```

and

```
Map(x => x.Query).Column("PNL_QUERY").CustomType("StringClob")
                                     .CustomSqlType("Long");
```

and

```
Map(x => x.Query).Column("PNL_QUERY").CustomType("Long");
```

and  nothing works. All of them return `""` in the Query field, when I load some entity from database.

How could I map this type of column in Oracle?

Thank you.

Comment: As a random thought, maybe you should try to declare this Long type in a custom Dialect overriding the RegisterLargeObjectTypeMappings() method from the oracle dialect see : https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/src/NHibernate/Dialect/Oracle8iDialect.cs#L124

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution:

To get the `LONG` columns working, in the ado.net oracle provider we have to set the `OracleCommand.InitialLONGFetchSize` property to `-1`. So we have to override the Oracle Driver from `OracleDataClientDriver` class. Something like this:

using NHibernate.Driver;
using Oracle.DataAccess.Client;

```
namespace MyProject
{
    public class OracleDriverExtended : OracleDataClientDriver
    {
        public override void AdjustCommand(System.Data.IDbCommand command)
        {
            OracleCommand cmd = command as OracleCommand;
            if (cmd != null)
                cmd.InitialLONGFetchSize = -1;
        }
    }
}
```

And in the `hibernate.cfg.xml` set this custom driver to the `connection.driver_class` property:

```
<property name="connection.driver_class">
   MyProject.Data.OracleDriverExtended,
   MyProject
</property>
```

Now, NHibernate can read the `LONG` types from Oracle.

I found the solution here http://sonyarouje.com/2012/11/07/nhibernate-and-oracle-long-varchar-field/